# TextView changes in Log.d, but doesn't change in actual application

Tags: java, android, textview

I have a `navigation_header.xml` where I have two `TextView`: one if ID `navigationUserName` and the other with ID `navigationUserEmail`. These `TextView` have placeholder values: John Doe and JohnDoe@gmail.com respectively. I want to change these values to the actual name and email of the user. I am handling this during the login process. Once the login is successful change the values. This can be seen below:

```
 mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailText, passwordText)
                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

                                        // Inflate view to be able to access the fields to update the name and email
                                        View inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.navigation_header, null);

                                        // TextView
                                        TextView loggedUserName = inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.navigationUserName);
                                        TextView loggedUserEmail = inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.navigationUserEmail);

                                        Log.d("Test", loggedUserName.getText().toString());
                                        Log.d("Test", loggedUserEmail.getText().toString());

                                        // Setting TextView to logged user's info
                                        loggedUserName.setText(user.getDisplayName());
                                        loggedUserEmail.setText(user.getEmail());

                                        Log.d("Test1", loggedUserName.getText().toString());
                                        Log.d("Test1", loggedUserEmail.getText().toString());

                                        // Start home activity and close main activity
                                        Intent home = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                                        startActivity(home);
                                        finish();
```

Authenticate the user, inflate the view where the `TextView` that I want to change are located, change them, and redirect to the home activity. This code is working, but it is not working at the same time. When I check the values on the `Log.d` I get the following results:

```
2023-08-21 20:11:17.258 13602-13602 Test      D  John Doe
2023-08-21 20:11:17.259 13602-13602 Test      D  JohnDoe@gmail.com
2023-08-21 20:11:17.259 13602-13602 Test1     D  User One
2023-08-21 20:11:17.259 13602-13602 Test1     D  UserOne@gmail.com
```

So the values are changing, but they are not changing in the screen of the application. What can cause this sort of behavior?

Update: I've kept testing since I posted and it seems that the value is being overwritten. How? I have no clue. But that seems to be the case since I added a `Log.d` on the `Home Activity` which is where the app redirects to and the values are still coming up as John Doe and JohnDoe@gmail.com.

Comment: You have inflated the view but you have not set it on the screen. This line: `View inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.navigation_header, null);`. You need to use the same-view (which is set as content view on the screen) to get the email and name field .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by doing the following:

1. Instead of handling populating the data in the Login Activity, I handled it in the Home Activity which is the Activity the user gets redirected to after login in.
2. I changed the following code:

```
View inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.navigation_header, null);
TextView loggedUserName = inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.navigationUserName);
TextView loggedUserEmail = inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.navigationUserEmail);
```

to this:

```
NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(id.navigation_view);
View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
TextView loggedUserName = header.findViewById(R.id.navigationUserName);
TextView loggedUserEmail = header.findViewById(R.id.navigationUserEmail);
```

and it worked! Now the fields are populated by the data of the logged user.